# Booting Custom 64 bit Kernel for RPI 3 on QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, boot, qemu

I have compiled a 64 bit kernel for Raspberry pi 3 to use with raspbian.
I did it following this tutorial
https://devsidestory.com/build-a-64-bit-kernel-for-your-raspberry-pi-3/.

As I finished, I ended up with a raspberry image which supposedly used a 64 bit kernel, and the kernel Image.

However, when I run 

`> qemu-system-aarch64 -kernel Image -cpu cortex-a53 -m 512 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda raspbian64.img`

Nothing happens, its like it cant find the kernel.
Is there a way to debug QEMU ? Should I use `versatiblepb` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

This is an incorrect command line. The 'versatilepb' board is an old development board for 32-bit ARM -- it has no support at all for 64-bit CPUs, and passing -cpu cortex-a53 with -M versatilepb is like trying to jam a Core2Duo CPU into the socket on an i386 motherboard.

You need to build a kernel which will work with one of the 64-bit ARM boards that QEMU emulates (currently 'virt', 'xlnx-ep108' or 'xlnx-zcu102', but I strongly recommend 'virt') and use that board and kernel together. Mismatching board and kernel will not work.

Comment: Ohh, that makes a lot of sense. But what I need is to have a GUI, I want to emulate raspbian and other peripherals while having access to a GUI, which I can't do with virt right? Would it work with xlnx ?

Comment: Although I would still have the same problem, because I don't have a config file to compile the kernel for xlnx :(

Comment: For pure emulation I think the PCI graphics cards should work with the virt board. virtio-gpu-pci is the recommended option (because it works with KVM as well).